# Get rows for which child rows have been updated recently

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `businesses` and `items`.  I'm trying to get last 9 businesses with the most recent item updates based on `updated_at` column in the `items` table.

I believe this gives me the last 9 business_id's I need:

```
SELECT distinct business_id
FROM items
ORDER BY items.updated_at desc limit 9
```

So I did it as a join and added another column to selection, it returns different results.

```
SELECT b.*, i.updated_at as last_updated, i.business_id as business_id
FROM businesses AS b
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT business_id, updated_at
      FROM items
      ORDER BY updated_at DESC 
      LIMIT 9) AS i
ON b.id = i.business_id
```

I definitely need the `updated_at` column from `items` table so I know the actual date. But once I add it in the select statement with distinct, it returns totally different results, as I'm assuming the row is no longer distinct since id + updated_at make each row unique.

Adding SQL schema as requested:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b44295

If we do a `limit 3` in the query on that above data, it should return:

```
---------------------------------------
| business_name | updated_at          |
---------------------------------------
| Business Two  | 2018-01-22 23:38:05 |
---------------------------------------
| Business One  | 2018-01-02 23:38:05 |
---------------------------------------
| Business Five | 2018-01-01 23:39:51 |
---------------------------------------
```

Comment: "So I did it as a join and added another column to selection, it returns different results."  "SELECT distinct business_id" vs ""SELECT business_id, updated_at
      FROM items"   logical it returns different results..

Comment: Provide example data on sqlfiddle.com and provide expected request based on that example data... It's hard to reverse engineer a query without knowing table structure and data to get a working solution..

Comment: Added SQLfiddle schema data as requested.